# Comments from "If A is noetherian then Spec(A) is noetherian"

Tags: discussion, comment

[Removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19733/if-a-is-noetherian-then-speca-is-noetherian/) by request.

-1. Please do not give complete answers to homework questions. – Qiaochu Yuan♦ 2 hours ago

@Qiaochu: I felt i should provide an answer so i gave, and google made work easy for me. – Chandru1 2 hours ago
@Chandru1: I do not see how either of those things constitutes an argument that you should give complete answers to homework questions. – Qiaochu Yuan♦ 2 hours ago

@Qiaochu: Listen, this is actually ones own opinion. Please do not interfere. If i feel i should give an answer i will. Why do you have problems with that. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Qiaochu: You may feel that it's not good for this site, but i feel if the student gets an answer for a question, he/she may replicate the idea when he/she sees it next time. Now is that wrong. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Qiaochu: It's not always that i pose a full answer. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Qiaochu: And take a look at Natalia's questions. All questions are motivating one's and she seems to be a student who can do well if given an idea or trick to a problem. – Chandru1 1 hour ago
4
@Chandru1: I am not interfering, in the sense that I am not preventing you from posting anything. I am politely asking that you do not do this in the future. I agree that students do well if given an idea; ideas are much better than complete solutions, and hints are even better than that. – Qiaochu Yuan♦ 1 hour ago

@Qiachu: I am not at all angry with you QY. I understand in what sense you meant. I am just saying that giving people answers sometimes isn't a bad idea either as they can replicate the idea once they see it. – Chandru1 1 hour ago
3   up voted
@Chandru1: For all your disclaimers, you have a penchance for reacting rather strongly and aggressively to any criticism, and tell people "don't interfere", or "it's just my opinion." Well, gues what, nobody is interfering, and other people are also "just expressing their opinion." If you can't handle criticism of any kind (as your reactions suggest), then this site will give you a very big ulcer at a very young age. – Arturo Magidin 1 hour ago

@Arturo: And you have a strong penchance for interfering when discussion is between me and Qiaochu. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Chandru1: Look up the word "interfering". I don't think it means what you think it means. And thank you for proving my point so well, yet again. P.S. If you want to have a private conversation, you shouldn't be having it in a public forum. – Arturo Magidin 1 hour ago

@Arturo: Well, you are the one who started it. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Chandru1: What is it I started? Did I start reacting strongly and aggressively to comments? Did I start misusing the word "interfere"? Did I start trying to have private conversations in public fora? Oh, wait. I "started" by saying things you don't like, and you reacted both violently and completely out of proportion. So, again, thank you for illustrating my point so well. I shudder at the thought of how you will react to the referee report if you ever submit a paper... – Arturo Magidin 1 hour ago

@Arturo: Look, this type of argument will keep on continuing and it will not stop. My comments are directed to Qiaochu, if he says that i was aggressive then i shall agree. When we both were discussing how can you say that i was aggressive. If you feel that way i can't help. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Arturo: And it's none of your business to worry about how i shall react when someone referees my paper. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

@Chandru1: So, let's stop it, just after you get your final attempt at a jab in? Sigh... – Arturo Magidin 1 hour ago

@Arturo: Phew.. finally discussion ended. – Chandru1 1 hour ago

Comment: I think this is another argument for a defined policy on homework questions, if we want to prevent situations like these.

Comment: This situation is not about homework; it is mostly about Chandru1 reacting inappropriately to criticism. In any case, I've become somewhat pessimistic about the prospects of a sharply-defined homework policy which would likely be too hard to enforce, and I think for the time being that attempting to convince more active users not to post complete answers to homework questions is likely to be more effective.

Comment: It seems to me that, apart from a very few users like Chandru1, most people adhere to the policy of "no complete solutions to standard exercises for people, who are trying to learn mathematics". I was very pessimistic and am positively surprised by the reality at the moment.

Comment: If something is not marked as homework, but seems homeworkish, is there an accepted policy?  I've fully answered a question or two which seemed like homework, though the question asker specifically stated it wasn't.

Comment: I have taken to asking in a comment about questions which I thought looked homework-ish, for exactly this reason.  Most good students only need a couple of little well-worded hints to work through the problem on their own...

Comment: What about those that are self learning?  I am not in any university and my questions come from books I am reading, a nice detail answer is very helpful, yet, I would like to solve the problem myself; however, on the other foot I would not like "hints" that I don't get.

Comment: Sorry, for the double comment.  We all have been on the internet long enough to know that flame wars happens and I think a vague policy is good and just try to keep the ship on the direction rather than worrying if its a bit off course, there are just so many voice here, plus this place is for the general public, not like overflow(math) which is for experts.